# Country suggestion list with Flag and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to build a country suggestion list with flag included in the result selected. I am able to achieve the suggestion box based on name but I want in the resulting text box to show the country flag  as well the country selected.

The other requirement is to show by default a country(say USA) with the flag in it rather a plain textbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/SfUYg/

PS. In my code I am trying to show the flag in the textbox with id 'country'. It works fine in the drop down list. I am also trying to show the default flag with text in the same textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need an image placeholder for the flag. I don't think you can add it inside a textfield.

Here is a simple version:

http://jsfiddle.net/SfUYg/1/

Comment: +1 ed mate thanks for the brilliant ans I need it actually inside the text box as per my requirements...

Comment: I found a way to do the same by wrapping the text box and place holder in a background image. Accepted the answer. thanks mate